# Extracting mesh from dynamic mesh in Google Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm a bit stuck with Tango device. I want to export a mesh built with the dynamic mesh prefab in Unity. I have seen the Tango3DRExtractWholeMesh function, but it's not working for me.

I have defined the output variables to fill out, and then call the function saving the status in another variable. Something like this:

```
Vector3[] verts;
Vector3[] normals;
Color32[] colors;
int[] indices;
int numV, numT;
Tango3DReconstruction.Status status =m_tangoApplication.Tango3DRExtractWholeMesh(verts, normals, colores, indexes, out numV, out numT)
```

But Tango does not do anything at this point. I have checked Tango manager parameters and activate all 3D reconstruction's.

Should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

I know you got it working but for the other people.

Use `TangoApplication.Tango3DRExtractWholeMesh()`

from:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-meshing#tango_application_settings

Dont forget to initialize your arrays (vertices, normals, triangles and colors) so they are big enough to contain the data from the mesh and then it works.

The problem is we dont yet know what size to initialize the arrays with.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fixed in Mira release which has new exporting functions. It is possible to export the mesh obj model.